# How to upload files to another user's Google Drive without asking permission every time?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

Is there any way to upload files to another user's Google Drive without asking for login or verification code each time except the first time?

Until now I used pydrive, but it asks to login each time. Is there anyway other than this, such that a key or something to use to skip the login of the user?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358692/how-can-i-use-the-google-drive-api-to-transfer-a-file-to-another-users-drive

Comment: @utility that is not iam looking for

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/python you would find a way to store the OAuth credentials.

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/questions/24419188/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419188/automating-pydrive-verification-process)

Comment: are you requesting the right [scope](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes)?
you'll need to cache the tokens and use full drive scope

Answer (score 5):

To clarify: you want to enable others to upload files into your own Google Drive? If that is the case, you can do this with this embed widget that you can copy & paste into your website: http://developers.cloudwok.com

If you want to allow users to upload files to a random Google Drive account of some other user, that won't work because the other user must give permission.