# Upload a file into Google Drive using google api call

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I created a google app in marketplace which helps to login the user using gmail. With that i added extra scope to access drive files.

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

This is used to access drive files of the permitted user. I have access token, refresh token and all of that user. Now i need to upload a file(pdf,excel Sheet  or anything) automatically from my system into the google user's drive account.
How can i achieve it? I got permission from user to access his drive account. now how can i upload a file into his drive? may i need to write code manually or is there ways to upload a file using google api?

Answer (score 1):

I only found a [sample script](https://www.bettercloud.com/monitor/the-academy/allow-anyone-to-upload-files-directly-to-your-drive/) on how to allow anyone to upload files directly to your Drive. From other user's account, try to run this [script](https://script.google.com/a/google.com/d/1x3p9ZAv-SafEK06r_Vr7fVuUNtEfBg1SGhmSYWjQ0kuPTk-y55a7Nink/edit?usp=sharing):

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');            
}

function uploadFiles(form) {      
  try {        
    var dropbox = "Work_Collector";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);

    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();

  } catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }      
}
```

You can also check this related thread: [How can I use the Google Drive API to transfer a file to another user's Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358692/how-can-i-use-the-google-drive-api-to-transfer-a-file-to-another-users-drive)